# jquery validate two panels individual

Tags: jquery, validation, panels

I am using jquery having two panel in my form one is Registration panel and another is login panel.

I want to validate them individually.

Right now tow panel validating at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally having a different ID for each panel (or I would call it div) and assigning validating code to each one separately should do.. for IDs `div1` and `div2` you would use `$("#div1")` and `$("#div2")` respectively

if this is still unclear then please show us some code to better understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

seperate them in 2 forms.

```
<form id ='a'>
<!-- panel 1 -->
</form>
<form id='b'>
<!-- panel 2 -->
</form>
```